# $\prod_{i=1}^{n} (3 +\frac{1}{a_i})$ cannot be a power of 2 if $a_i \equiv \pm 1 \pmod 6$

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic, contest-math, congruence-relations

I have encountered this problem and I can't solve it.

If $a_i \equiv 1 \pmod 6$ or $a_i \equiv -1 \pmod \ 6$ and $a_i \ne \pm 1$, for every $i \in \{1, 2, .., n\}$, then prove that
$$\prod_{i=1}^{n} \left(3 +\frac{1}{a_i}\right)$$ cannot be a power of $2$. Using induction, I proved that
$$2^{n + 1} \lt \prod_{i=1}^{n} \left(3 +\frac{1}{a_i}\right)$$ Then I tried working$\mod 6$,$\mod4$ and $\mod 3$, but I couldn't solve it. Have you got any ideas?

Comment: What if $a_i=-1$ for all $i$? If the $a_i$ have to be positive, then the product is at least $3^n$, so if your proof by induction was correct, it follows that $3^n\le 2^{n+1}$ and $(3/2)^n\le 2$ which means that $n=1$.

Comment: Oh, well, I forgot about $-1$.

Comment: My mistake, I have revised the proof and it contained a mistake.

Comment: So is it true and given that this product is indeed bounded by $2^{n+1}$? OP, it is on the person writing the question 
to be clear, and this is hard to follow with the corrections made in the comments.

Comment: Sorry for the mistakes, I think I have corrected them.

Comment: Can you outline the proof of the bound by $2^{n+1}$ though? I'm not sure I see that. But yes given that as per Mastrem's comments, the rest is relatively straightfoward.

Comment: Well, first of all, the case for $n = 1$, $3 + \frac{1}{a_1}$ is clearly not a power of two. If $n = 2$, $(3 + \frac{1}{a_1})(3 + \frac{a_2}) > 3^2 > 2^3$. Now assume $\prod_{i = 1}^{n}(3 + \frac{1}{a_i}) > 2^{n + 1}$ and show that $\prod_{i = 1}^{n + 1}(3 + \frac{1}{a_i}) > 2^{n + 2}$. But $\prod_{i = 1}^{n + 1}(3 + \frac{1}{a_i}) > 2^{n + 1} (3 + \frac{1}{a_{n+1}}) > 2^{n + 2}$. The other assumptions I made were false.

Comment: Ah yes, it is bounded from below by $2^{n+1}$. And I mispoke, what is true and what I should have said, is that if it were **upper bounded** by $2^{n+1}$ then solving the rest would be straightfoward.

Comment: Yes, indeed. I am sorry for the original mistakes.

Comment: This does look like an interesting problem!

Answer (score 7):

This does not hold. Examples:
$$(3+\frac1{-7})(3+\frac1{-5})=2^3$$
and
$$(3+\frac1{17})(3+\frac1{19})(3+\frac1{29})(3+\frac1{143})(3+\frac1{215}) = 2^8.$$